# Cakephp3 save many to many table example tags

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create a multi select drop down in Cakephp3. Then update a many to many

I have a post table and tags table and a post_tags table the models have the following foreign keys

```
PostsTable
$this->hasMany('PostTags', [
     'foreignKey' => 'post_id'
]);


TagsTable
$this->hasMany('PostTags', [
     'foreignKey' => 'tag_id'
]);

PostTagsTable
$this->belongsTo('Tags', [
    'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
     'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

the post tags table has a post_id and tag_id

in my post add view I have

echo $this->Form->input('tags', ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'select4', 'label' => false, 'options' => $tags, 'multiple' => 'multiple']);

When I debug in the controller I get

```
'tags' => [
    (int) 0 => '1',
    (int) 1 => '2'
],
```

When I look on stack overflow it seems I need to have this:
( I am not 100% sure this is correct)
A:

```
$data = [
    'tags' => [
        ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2]
    ]
]
```

I tried looping through the $tags  like but the debug results are pretty much the same:
Looping like this

```
<div class="input select">
<input type="hidden" name="tags"  value=""id="select4_">
<select name="tags[]" multiple="multiple" class="select4" size="7">
<?php
echo '<option id="tag1" value="tag1">option 1</option>'; 
echo '<option id="tag2" value="tag2" >option 2</option>';
?>
</select>
</div>
```

I will get

```
'tags' => [
    (int) 0 => 'tag1',
    (int) 1 => 'tag2'
],
```

Apparently I need to pass the values as shown in A: to the controller and then do

```
$post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Tags']]);
```

To make it all work. I would appreciate some help on this as I have been struggeling for days with this.
Thanks

Comment: I got it fixed in the end. By using cake bake. My table was posts and tags and post_tags. It should have been posts_tags. Once I changed it cake bake - baked in perfectly. Using the wrong table syntax mixed up things for me and I tried to fix a problem by going all wrong about it - by having the wrong table name cake bake created a hasMany instead of a belongsToMany relationship - hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

You'll want this in your template:

```
echo $this->Form->input('tags._ids', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => true,
    'options' => $tags,
]);
```

Then the Cake marshaller should fix it itself :) Make sure the entity has this property as accessible though! :-)

You can see the docs in action here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data